Azure DevOps classic pipelines path filter workaround for "Other Git" repo
I am in the process of setting up a build pipeline that is connected to an AWS CodeCommit repo requiring the "Other Git" option to be selected and configuring the pipeline through the classic GUI setup. Within the setup, I am not seeing an option to set up path filters. Are there alternative methods or workarounds to implement path filters for classic GUI pipelines using the "Other Git" repo option?
I haven't been able to identify any workarounds or features supported within the Azure DevOps classic pipeline setup to support path filters.

To set up triggers for a "Classic" (Designer-based Pipeline), you need to turn on the "Enable continuous integration" option and specify the path filters.
The following shows a Classic Pipeline using an "Other git" repository:


Thanks for the comment! I already have branch filters added as described in your comment. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of the path filters that can be set in the YAML pipeline.
For example:
paths:
include:
- src/path_example

Understood. It doesn't look like that option is available with the Other Git. Why not use a YAML pipeline?

I am afraid that the Other Git based Classic Pipeline doesn't support using Path Filter in Azure DevOps.
It only supports to using Branch filters for the time being.
For example:

Since you are using the AWS CodeCommit repo, it only supports to use the Other Git Option to create the Classic Pipeline.
It doesn't support using the AWS Repo to create the YAML Pipeline.
For a workaround, you need to migration the AWS Repo to Azure DevOps Repo. Then you can set the Path filter in both classic Pipeline and YAML Pipeline.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
